# HTML and CSS, border not wrapping around col

Tags: html, css

I'm using normalize.css and grid.css from responsive grid system. In below example, there's a div class called project-box under div class row. Anyone know why project-box border doesn't wrap around the two columns? Why does it only show border on top? Please explain and help! Thank you!!

```css
.row {
  border: 1px solid black;
  max-width: 1140px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.project-box {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="project-box">

    <div class="col span-1-of-2">
      <p>Hello</p>
    </div>

    <div class="col span-1-of-2">
      <p>Hi there</p>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What do you mean it's not wrapping around the two div's? it's working for me

Comment: I'm using grid layout from responsivegridsystem, could it be that's what's messing me up? Kinda want to find out reason why

Comment: you can use the developer tools to find out what's going on https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Common_questions/What_are_browser_developer_tools

Comment: @LawrenceYoon Please include `<link>` elements in the snippet, as you've said that you're using libraries.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know the grid.css library, but I guess that "col span-1-of-2" somehow means 50%

This is the code that I tryed and worked fine:

```html
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang='en'>
      <head>
        <meta charset='UTF-8'>
        <style href='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/normalize/8.0.0/normalize.css'></style>
        <style>
          .row{
            border    : 1px solid black;
            max-width : 1140px;
            margin    : 0 auto;}
          .project-box{
            border  : 1px solid red;
            /* I just added "display: flex;" */
            display : flex;}
          /* WITH THE FOLLOWING RULE I TRY TO EMULATE GRID.CSS */
          .col{width : 50%;}
        </style>
      </head>
      <body>
        <div class='row'>
          <div class='project-box'>
            <div class='col span-1-of-2'>
              <p>Helo</p>
            </div>
            <div class='col span-1-of-2'>
              <p>Hi there</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </body>
    </html>
```